# Why is this deleted post not actually deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I was looking through the annotated posts, and I came across: [While connecting to the room in EnableX, I get an error message - “Token Invalid”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57821571/while-connecting-to-the-room-in-enablex-i-get-an-error-message-token-invalid).

This question is both deleted, and not deleted, at the same time.

The [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57821571/timeline) and [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57821571/revisions) state that it's currently deleted:

[image: Screenshot of timeline showing a deleted post, viewed by a <10k user]

When it's clearly not, as I (a <10k user) can see it:

[image: Screenshot of the post in question, it's marked as locked and not accepting any answers or interactions, despite the revision history showing it as deleted]

What's going on?

Comment: Weird. Mods have a lot of power, so they can delete and undelete any post. However, I can see it as a logged-out user.

Comment: Congrats, you found Schrödinger's question.

Comment: Similar to this question [Why is this question that was deleted by the Community user not deleted?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408326), I guess. I interpret the answer there that this is a rare hick-up in the engine.

Comment: It seems that for some reason, a moderator spam deleted that question. The deletion was then undone, but not recorded in the history. The post wasn't unlocked either. It's really strange.

Comment: @Tom Good catch with that, it sounded familiar, but was having trouble finding the meta post.

Comment: It wasn't me who found that question, it was Stack Overflow. It is listed under "Related" in the right sidebar :D (even before I linked it here in the comments).

Comment: @Tom I don't believe you, that related section never has anything useful in it! :p

Comment: The post has a deleted answer, it was deleted as rude/abusive (I think it is not, although it really does not look well, but nothing insulting).

Comment: The quality of the English in the deleted answer is much better than expected, which usually indicates ***plagiarism*** (there are exceptions). Google doesn't return anything (of value) by using exact phrases (e.g., "once the token key has been used for the session" and *"you must use it within 15 minutes to connect to the room"*), but it is also becoming more or more useless for searching for exact phrases as it insists on returning something anyway, instead of an empty search result.

Comment: @peterh: I think it is the same reason given for spam. It could also apply to plagiarism.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks. That is a serious problem, falsely signing things as abuse while they are not...

Comment: @peterh, answer was appropriately deleted as abuse of the system.  I don't know why the question survived.

Comment: @StephenRauch: Maybe the lock it has prevented proper deletion?